# Drupal dependency vurenabilities check

Tags: php, security, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I am using **Drupal 8.9.15** (with composer and Docker).
The problem is that the vurenabilities dependency check tool detects about 200 issues and most of them are realted to Drupal, and most of them to jqueryui which is used by Drupal, for example:

> /web/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/node_modules/grunt-html/vnu.jar/META-INF/maven/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/pom.xml

> /web/core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/lodash/package.json

> /web/core/node_modules/ftp/package.json

Why is it happening  if Drupal is secure CMS?
Is it possible to fix it somehow? I see that the packages are downloading automatically to node_modules in drupal core directory.

Comment: This looks like a good question for the Drupal community. By the way, what makes you think that "Drupal is secure CMS"? It's pretty common that such node packages are not always up-to-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately part of the reason that it's recommended to upgrade to Drupal 9 (believe me, the path is much better than from 7 -> 8).

It's known by the Drupal community that jQuery UI is no longer supported [as mentioned in this change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3067969). The recommended course of action is to upgrade to Drupal 9.

To answer your question, "Why is it happening if Drupal is secure CMS?" Well, it is as secure as it can be and as secure as its end users allow it to be.  When Drupal 8 was released, jQuery UI was still supported.  Now that Drupal 9 is released, jQuery UI is not part of core.

If you upgrade to Drupal 9, the security issues with jQuery UI will no longer be of concern.

Now, this is only for Drupal Core.  There may still be some contrib modules that use jQuery UI elements, but that is not the responsibility of the core maintainers to watch for.  However, as listed in the change record, they have mentioned a few contrib modules that still use those assets.